# How to rewrite java loop with saving temporary result to java8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there some nice way to rewrite the following loop, in which I am saving temporary results, using Java 8 `Stream`?

```
    Integer resultByCon1 = null, resultByCon2 = null;
    for (Foo foo : bar) {
        if (conditional1 && conditional2) {
            return foo.getResult();
        }
        if (conditional1) {
            resultBycon1 = foo.getResult();
        }
        if (conditional2) {
            resultBycon2 = foo.getResult();
        }
    }
    return resultByCon1 != null ? resultByCon1
            : (resultByCon2 != null ? resultByCon2 : bar.get(0).getResult());
```

Comment: Too little information. What are `conditional1` and `conditional2`? They depend on the actual `foo`, right? Is it intentional to return the result of the *last*  matching `foo` after the loop? Is `bar` really something expensive to iterate, justifying that complicated structure?

Comment: list just contain couple of elements like under 10 and yes conditional depends on foo and yes I want last matching

Comment: ok  it could be also first match because the list should not contain duplicate according to condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that could be considered more elegant, but it requires a full pass for each condition. That is, it will return as soon as it finds an element matched by a condition, but it only evaluates one condition per pass (to preserve condition precedence). If you're dealing with a small list, you may be willing to take the hit:

```
List<Predicate<Foo>> conditions = Arrays.asList(
        foo -> conditional1 && conditional2,
        foo -> conditional1,
        foo -> conditional2,
        foo -> true
);

return conditions.stream()
        .map(condition -> bar.stream().filter(condition))
        .map(Stream::findFirst)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .findFirst()
        .map(Optional::get)
        .map(Foo::getResult)
        .get();
```

Comment: I think this returns the first item that matches `conditional1` (or `conditional2` in the third pass), where OP's code only short-circuits for `conditional1 && conditional2`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner That's true, but I suspect that's an unintentional side-effect of OP's inability to short-circuit the second and third conditions, in order to give precedence to the first. (In which case it may be acceptable to replace `findFirst` with `findAny`, but I won't go that far.)

Comment: But OP is saying in a comment that returning the last item is intentional. And OP is also saying that the list contains under 10 elements, so I don't see any benefit in short-circuiting IMO.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Right again, I missed that comment. Though I'm still skeptical, to be honest. Short-circuiting seems to be necessary for the first condition, so I'll acknowledge this solution is broken if we do need to "long-circuit" the others. For now, I'll leave it here until OP offers some feedback.

Comment: Yes, I agree. We're missing information here in order to do better. Btw, very nice approach to stream the predicates ;)

Comment: hm nice solution. Probably in my list there is no different if it is last or first occurrence

Comment: I don’t see the advantage of using multiple adjacent `map` steps like `.map(condition -> bar.stream().filter(condition)) .map(Stream::findFirst)`. Why not just `.map(condition -> bar.stream().filter(condition).findFirst())`?

Comment: @Holger It's just a stylistic preference. I don't like long lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, though I'm not sure how "nice" it is:

```
Integer[] resultByCon = new Integer[2];
return bar.stream()
          .filter (f -> {
                          if (conditional1 && conditional2) {
                              return true;
                          }
                          if (conditional1) {
                              resultBycon[0] = foo.getResult();
                          }
                          if (conditional2) {
                              resultBycon[1] = foo.getResult();
                          }
                          return false;
                        })
          .map(Foo::getResult)
          .findFirst()
          .orElseGet (() -> resultByCon[0] != null ? 
                      resultByCon[0] : 
                      (resultByCon[1] != null ? resultByCon[1] : bar.get(0).getResult()));
```

It contains all the logic in a single `Stream` pipeline, but it's probably less readable than your original code.

You may be able to do better using `reduce()`.

Comment: hm thx for solution java8 solution but as I see it I will stay in java7 because it is more readable for me